# changing source for packages after debian 8 cdrom install

Tags: debian, package-management

Setting up a first home file server. Fresh Debian 8 installed.

When trying to install nmap [wanted ncat to test syncthing] apt asks me to insert the CD..  In the future i might be far from the box and want to make sure it can stay headless and wont ask such a thing again.

```
After this operation, 21.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.4.0 _Jessie_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20160402-13:26'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

Where should i change this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment out a line that starts with this:

```
deb cdrom
```

Comment: Curious to know if this is actually a bug or not. This doesn't happen with netinstall, so it's a bit of a surprise when using the larger ISO.